# How can I automatically send an email with an excel file containing submissions for a form rather than an email per submission?

Tags: plugins, forms, email, csv

I recently took over web admin for a nonprofit organization and one of the things they would like changed with their site is to have multiple forms such as contact, volunteer, donations, more info, etc. They would like this data sent in an email so that it can be sent to focus group members but need it sent in a daily/ weekly email rather than an email for each individual submission. I think that an excel file is the best way to accomplish what they want and I have looked at several form plugins but they only support manual export of excel files. Is there either a plugin that supports emailing excel files or is there another way I can automate an export and email that export? Thanks in advance!

Comment: gravity form with Gravity Forms To Excel AddOn give a try that is how i use it at work.

Comment: Although I looked at Gravity forms, I eventually decided to go with embedded google forms because it was free and the organization is a nonprofit. In addition, the well known format and accessibility of google spreadsheets makes it easier for those requiring the data to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish what they were looking to do was to recreate and create new forms in Google Drive and then embed them into the page. This allowed there to be a live spreadsheet with responses that any admin could access.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/). You just need to create and save your excel doc first.

```
$attachments = array(ABSPATH . '/uploads/my.xlsx');

wp_mail($email, 'Testing Attachment' , 'This is an Excel doc', $attachments);
```